# How to convert JSON file to new line delimited using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I have a standalone Google Script project that makes nested JSON from fetch URL.
Original code by [iAmOren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5792509/iamoren).

```js
function unFlat(fj) {
  let date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
  var arr=[];
  var objL1, objL2, objL3;
  var prev_level;
  for(var i=0; i<fj.length;i++) {
    var obj=fj[i];
    switch(Number(obj.level)) {
      case 3:
        objL3={};
        objL3.name=obj.name;
        objL3.leads=obj.leads;
        objL3.cost=obj.cost;
        objL3.revenue=obj.revenue;
        objL2.place.push(objL3);
        prev_level=3;
        break;
      case 2:
        objL2={};
        objL2.path=obj.path;
        objL2.name_postfix=obj.name_postfix;
        objL2.path_com=obj.path_com;
        objL2.name=obj.name;
        objL2.place=[];
        objL1.partner.push(objL2);
        prev_level=2;
        break;
      case 1:
        if(prev_level==3) arr.push(objL1);
        objL1={};
        objL1.report_date=date;
        objL1.name=obj.name;        
        objL1.partner=[];
        prev_level=1;
        break;
    }
  }
  if(fj.length) arr.push(objL1);
  //Save JSON file on my Drive  
  let fileSets = {
    title: 'JSON_Test.json',
    mimeType: 'application/json'
  };
  let blob = Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(arr), "application/vnd.google-apps.script+json");
  Drive.Files.insert(fileSets, blob);  
}
```

It works, file appears in my Google drive. Then I want to use it as data set for BigQuery, but it does not work.
When I try to upload this file to BigQuery it returns an error: `Failed to create table: Error while reading table: my_json, error message: Failed to parse JSON: No object found when new array is started.; BeginArray returned false; Parser terminated before end of string`.
I think it is because my JSON file is not new line delimited.
Any way where I'm wrong and how to fix it?

Example of [my JSON file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XzzgmHoh3Om65CW4J-WvjGJ_GZQvjwb7/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Just found solution by myself

```js
//Save JSON file on my Drive  
  let fileSets = {
    title: 'JSON_Test.json',
    mimeType: 'application/json'
  };
  let blob = Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(arr[0]), "application/vnd.google-apps.script+json"); //modified
  Drive.Files.insert(fileSets, blob);
```